# To find consecutive whitespace characters in input

Tags: python, python-3.x, spaces, counting

I am to find out the number of consecutive whitespace in input. Let's say if input is:

```
'          hi there'
```

I want to get the number '10' as that is the longest 'consecutive' spaces in that string instead of '11' which is the number of all spaces.

Any kind of help is most appreciated.

Thanks! I understand how to do that now for one string, but the input is supposed to be multiple lines and I can't seem to work that in with it. Input is something like this:

```
'hkhkh

 hk           hk`
```

with about 5 different lines in one input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

my_string = '          hi there'
current_max = 0

# First, break the string up into individual strings for each space
split_string = my_string.split(" ")

# Then, iterate over the list returning each string
# along with an iterator containing all the matches
# that follow it in a connected run
# e. g. "aaabbaa" would produce a data structure akin to this:
# [("a", ["a", "a", "a"]), ("b", ["b", "b"]), ("a", ["a", "a"])]
for c, sub_group in groupby(split_string):
    # If the string is not an empty string (e. g. it was not a space)
    # we are not interested in it - so skip this group.
    if c != '':
        continue

    # Get the length of the run of spaces
    i = len(list(sub_group))
    if i > current_max:
        current_max = i

print("The longest run of spaces is", current_max)
```

Comment: Nice.  What do you think of replacing the for-loop with:

`max_len = max(len(list(subgroup)) for substring, subgroup in groupby(split_string) if substring == '')`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - totally licit, but harder for a beginner to follow :-)

Answer (score 0):

what do you define as whitespace. just spaces or also:
tab (`\t`) 
carriage return (`\r`) 
newline (`\n`)

```
some_string = """hkhkh

 hk           hk



           and here"""

ls = longest_streak = 0
cs = current_streak = 0

for character in some_string:

    # or some other test will depend on your use case (numbers? '"/%$!@#$ etc.).
    # if not character in (' ', '\n', '\r', '\t'): 
    if character.isalpha():
        if cs > ls:
            ls = cs
        cs = 0
        continue

    elif character in ('\r', '\n'):
        continue

    else:
        cs += 1


print(ls)
```

the `elif` will continue on the current streak if it encounters the `\r \n` hidden characters, you could also add `\t` if you want to take tabs into account.